# How to find the owner of bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I can't create AppID because my bundle identifier not unique. Can I somehow find who is owner of bundle identifier which I want to use?

Comment: I did. But there was many people before who work with this project and I suspect one of them use bundle identifier in his personal developer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Even if you ask everybody that once worked with your company, it could also always be somebody outside having fun using your company name.